# Order by one column inside other column

Tags: mysql, order-by

I've a MySQL table that looks like the following:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca67ac/1

I use it to build a grid where i put my content. The resultant is this:

[image]

I've to render every row separatelly but, inside every row, render it's content by column.
So, for this task i need to get the rows in this order: **1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7**.

column number **6** must come before **5** because it's first in the column order inside that row from left to right.

Is there any sorting method that i can use to achieve that? Order by row but order by column inside that order.

Comment: I get a vague idea about what you are trying to do, But your definition is far from clear. I mean your definition of the ordering and why 6 should be before 5. Are there any restrictions on the sizes and locations of the boxes? Because if not, I can think of quite complicated setups where what order you want is unclear.

Comment: Sorry if my problem was unclear. Every cell is used for content rendering. The problem is when content in cell 5 is larger than 4. In that case, cell 6 has an empty-ugly space on top of it. Example: http://imgur.com/af5HumI. That's why i want to order by row but order by column too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by doing the following:

```
SELECT nWidth, nHeight, nColumn, 
(SELECT MAX(t.nRow + (t.nHeigth - 1)) FROM test t WHERE t.nRow = tp.nRow 
GROUP BY t.nRow LIMIT 1) AS nRow
FROM test tp ORDER BY nRow, tp.nColumn
```

This will get the max from the row number plus it's heigth minus 1. 
So, if we have a row that has a cell with height equal or higher than 2, all its cells are going to be in the same row. So, inside that row, we order by Column.

Hope this helps someone.